# Printing matrices between text in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have seen a few examples over here where it was explained how to print a matrix to a .txt file. However, I haven't found a simple way to perform what I would like to do, which is to print several matrices that are written in a .txt in which additional text is also being printed. Note, this text is not meant to be a headers or something, therefore solutions using dataframe are not really suited.

supposing I have the following matrices:

```
M1 = np.zeros((6, 6))
M2 = np.zeros((6, 6))
M3 = np.zeros((6, 6))
```

I would like to print the matrix relative to the line on-top

```
with open("example.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("-------  MATRIX 1 ------------------------------------------------------------\n")    
    f.write("------- MATRIX 2 ---------------------------------------------------------\n")
    f.write("------- MATRIX 3 ---------------------------------------------------------\n")
```

The results I would be expecting would be a .txt file similar like this:

```
-------  MATRIX 1 ------------------------------------------------------------
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
-------  MATRIX 2 ------------------------------------------------------------
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
-------  MATRIX 3 ------------------------------------------------------------
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`numpy.savetxt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) is a proper choice for such case;
specific parameters allow to set *format*, *header* and *comment*:

```
with open('test.txt', "w") as f:
    np.savetxt(f, M1, fmt='%d', delimiter='   ', comments='', header="-------  MATRIX 1 ------------------------------------------------------------\n")
    np.savetxt(f, M2, fmt='%d', delimiter='   ', comments='', header="-------  MATRIX 2 ------------------------------------------------------------\n")
    np.savetxt(f, M3, fmt='%d', delimiter='   ', comments='', header="-------  MATRIX 3 ------------------------------------------------------------\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really just want to print only those 3 lines, you can use this. The delimiter is what you can use for the spacing, it is one white space as default, here I used 3 to somewhat match what you were looking for.

For some parameters that you can use for formatting, check [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html).

```
import numpy as np

M1 = np.zeros((6, 6))
M2 = np.zeros((6, 6))
M3 = np.zeros((6, 6))

with open("C:/temp/test.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("-------  MATRIX 1 ------------------------------------------------------------\n")    
    np.savetxt(f, M1, fmt='%g', delimiter='    ')
    f.write("\n-------  MATRIX 2 ------------------------------------------------------------\n")    
    np.savetxt(f, M2, fmt='%g', delimiter='    ')
    f.write("\n-------  MATRIX 3 ------------------------------------------------------------\n")    
    np.savetxt(f, M3, fmt='%g', delimiter='    ')
```

This code produces the following:

```
-------  MATRIX 1 ------------------------------------------------------------
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0

-------  MATRIX 2 ------------------------------------------------------------
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0

-------  MATRIX 3 ------------------------------------------------------------
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not such a good with `numpy` to know builtin workarounds, but you can get this output like that:

```
M1 = np.zeros((6, 6))
M2 = np.zeros((6, 6))
M3 = np.zeros((6, 6))
   
with open('example.txt', 'w') as f:
    for idx, matrix in enumerate((M1, M2, M3)):
        f.write(f'------- MATRIX {idx+1} ------------------------------------------------------------\n')
        for matrix_row in matrix:
            row ='    '.join(str(i) for i in matrix_row) + '\n'
            f.write(row)
```

Output:

```
------- MATRIX 1 ------------------------------------------------------------
0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
------- MATRIX 2 ------------------------------------------------------------
0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
------- MATRIX 3 ------------------------------------------------------------
0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
```

*If it's important to get `0` instead of `0.0`, it's possible to convert values to `int` before converting to `str` here:

```
row ='    '.join(str(int(i)) for i in matrix_row) + '\n'
```

OR define value types inside numpy array:

```
M1 = np.zeros((6, 6), dtype=int)
M2 = np.zeros((6, 6), dtype=int)
M3 = np.zeros((6, 6), dtype=int)
```

to get:

```
------- MATRIX 1 ------------------------------------------------------------
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
------- MATRIX 2 ------------------------------------------------------------
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
------- MATRIX 3 ------------------------------------------------------------
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
```